# DirectX tutorials/books

Tags: c#, directx, msdn

I would like to start learning directX [c#] and was wondering where I should learn it from. It seems like a waste of time to just grab an old tutorial that is bad precipice anymore.

I looked around and saw MSDN had one, but it seems pretty limited, so is there any other reliable and still relevant websites or books out for directx 10 or higher?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry Argent, this is too open-ended for SO. You'll have better luck searching Google and limiting the results time-frame to the last year (or whatever you want), or searching Amazon for books and sorting by rating.

Comment: I hadn't thought of refining results to more recent times. The amazon idea is pretty good too. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 4):

The MSDN content for using DirectX from C# is specifically the legacy Managed DirectX 1.1 assemblies which are indeed ancient, or is XNA Game Studio which is another option. XNA Game Studio does not support Direct3D 10 or 11 (or 64-bit native). See [DirectX and .NET](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2010/12/09/directx-and-net.aspx) for a summary.

The best option for learning DirectX 11 from C# today is to use either [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/) or [SlimDX](http://www.slimdx.org/).

As for [book recommendations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2014/04/07/book-recommendations.aspx), check out: Stenning, "Direct3D Rendering Cookbook", Packt Publishing (January 21, 2014)

Comment: Thanks for the book recommends! Ill look into sharp dx and skin dx. Cheers!